# GET and POST in JSON using requests in Python

Tags: python, json, api, for-loop

I am working on a project where I have to GET data from a link and then POST the data in another server after I have extracted the information that I needed from the data fetched. I am using the library requests for my GET and POST, and here's the code for extracting the data needed:

```
    ''' original data fetched
     result= {"version": "1.0","cmd":"list_metering","status":"success","devices":
     [{"deviceid":"xxxxx","model":"xxxx"},{"deviceid":"xxxxx","model":"xxxx"}]} '''

for devices in result['devices']:


    # delete the parameters I don't need
    final_data = removekey(devices,'model')

    # x.update(final_data) -> Trying dicts
    # x.append(final_data) -> Trying lists

    # Sending directly 
    resp = requests.post(url,json=final_data,headers=headers)

    no+=1
    if no== len(result['devices']):
        break
```

This is where I will call a function that will delete keys that are not needed and then I will take the rest and post it.

and I tried using the update() function for dictionaries but it didn't work due to the fact that I have the same keys so only one of the data will be considered. Lists work but I will get the data in this form:

```
[{"deviceid":"xxxxx","model":"xxxx"},{"deviceid":"xxxxx","model":"xxxx"}]
```

and I tried to use json=data and x.json() but both didn't work out for lists. However, if I send the data directly as it is shown in my first code, due to delays and I am not so sure what else, if i am lucky, full data will be sent, otherwise I keep losing some part of the data fetched.

How do I GET data in json and then send it back again in json for this case? My aim is to send the data as one bundle, all the devices together so I don't lose anything.

Here are the GET and POST I am using:

```
 # GET 
url_source = 'https://website'
url = requests.get(url_source)
result = url.json()

 # POST 
headers = {'charset':'utf-8','Content-Type':'application/json'}
url = "http://xxxx/_get_v1.php"
data = final_data
resp = requests.post(url,json=data,headers=headers)
```

Comment: Could you make it more clearly? Add sample GET/POST requests if possible.

Comment: I will do that boss.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, `devices` is not an invalid input(though a valid json). According @AhmedAl-haddad reply, we should send `{}`-formatted data.

If it means to remove 'model' from `devices` and send the updated GET response data as below.

```
# POST
headers = {'charset':'utf-8','Content-Type':'application/json'}
url = "http://xxxx/_get_v1.php"

# remove 'models'
map(lambda x: x.pop('model'), result['devices'])

# send result
resp = requests.post(url,json=result,headers=headers)
```

Or we need to send `device` in `devices` separately?

```
# send result  
for device in result['devices']:
    resp = requests.post(url,json=device,headers=headers)
```

As @JonDeen mentioned, you should read the **document** to get more details

Comment: True. In this case I might send them as list of dictionaries or a dictionary once a time. The reason why I am trying to send them all at once is because I fear losing a few of the data sent due to timeout or unstable network etc. In this case I have 2 'devices' but if I have more then the chance of losing the data while sending them is higher. But seemingly it is not possible to and I might need to contact the admin. The receiver is in php, but I don't know it so I am not sure what I should say to the admin? How can he fix it? He is receiving the data in json as shown in my post request.

Comment: @AhmedAl-haddad use 'keep-alive' to send the requests, check the response and send the same json until success

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to remove a key from a dictionary?
If so, use the syntax

```
 del myJson["myKey"]
```

Also consider using the [json-API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for simplicity if you want to manipulate the dataset and restructure it from lists vs. strings.

Also check the [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for example on submitting json.

Example (updated to remove unnecessary list update):

```py
devices=result['devices']
for i,device in enumerate(devices):

    # delete the parameters I don't need
    del device['model']

resp = requests.post(url,json=devices,headers=headers)
```

Comment: No, I already have a function that deletes the keys, but what I am asking about is what to do after that.

Comment: device is a _dict_ object, you don't need `devices[i]=device`

Comment: Pardon, I may have gotten confused, but isn't *device* a `dict`, and *devices* a `list`?

Comment: I actually got almost the same result as before although yours looks nicer. When I send what I get to the server I get {"Status" : 0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing" eventhough the respond that I receive is 200. This is when I use resp.text and resp.status_code respectively. Does this mean I have to contact the admin? Otherwise when I send the data in { } form, they get received.

Comment: @AhmedAl-haddad I guess you isolate `devices` from the `result` which is a list make it an invalid Json. You should replace `devices` in the `result` instead.

Comment: @JonDeen (devices is a list of dict :) @AhmedAI-haddad post `requests.post(url,json=result,headers=headers)`, it would work.

Comment: @AhmedAl-haddad - when sending json data, even though the server does not necessarily like the contents of the json, the server is able to generate a status json-message, which technically makes it a valid web-page response (`200`). I'm not familiar with the `json`-argument in connection with `requests.post`, but try using a `data`-argument with json stringified data as mentioned in the requests documentation I linked to. Without knowing exactly what fields/format the server is requesting, we cannot possibly know how to format your json correctly, in which case you should contact the admin.

Comment: @LittleQ - So is `devices[i]=device` needed or not?

Comment: @JonDeen NO for dict type, you can print `devices[i]` without the assignment

Comment: @LittleQ - naturally, but my examples assumes the payload is sent as a collated list *after* the `for`-loop, hence the `devices[i]=device` is needed to retain the changes.

Comment: @LittleQ `devices[i]` is a `dict`, `device` is a `dict`, `devices` is *not*. It's a list. _(a momentary pause followed by aha and a facepalm)_ And as you say, of course, the list only references the dict such that neither needs any updates. Sorry, my brain was obviously not built for multidimensionality!

Comment: @JonDeen `json = data` is how this is posted in requests. I honestly don't know how the data sent look like. I can use `url.json()` when I get json object.